# Really basic terrain generator

Tags: c++, beginner, random

This is my first attempt at writing a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) program, so bear with me. I tried to use as many methods as I learned in about a week-long period.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


void generator(char tree, char water, char land)
{
    const char tileList[] = {tree, water, land};
    int tileIndex = rand() % 3;

    std::cout << tileList[tileIndex] << " ";
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    while(true)
    {
        generator('T', '~', '.');
    }
}
```

*I took out comments to improve code readability.* What can be improved? What needs to be changed?

Comment: I didn't know Putin could code...

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg he has already [too many distractions](http://gigapica.geenstijl.nl/2011/09/putin_vladimir_putin_1.html) to be coding properly, although I'm sure he could pick it up if he wanted to ;-)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why the downvote?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This won't compile:

> ```
> void generator(char tree, char water, char land);
> // ...
> generator("T", "~", ".");
> ```

Because `generator` takes 3 `char`s, and you're giving it `const char*` instead.

Of course that's easy to fix, just make the params `char`s:

```
generator('T', '~', '.');
```

---

It would be better if the `generator` *generated*, instead of *printing*.
It's to preserve the single responsibility principle.
Like this:

```
char generator(char tree, char water, char land)
{
    const char tileList[] = {tree, water, land};
    int tileIndex = rand() % 3;
    return tileList[tileIndex];
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << generator('T', '~', '.') << " ";
    }
}
```

---

Of course the loop will never end... Are you ok with that?

---

Taking 3 `char`s as possible tiles doesn't seem too flexible. How about making it work with arbitrary number of tiles? Something like this:

```
char generator(const char * tiles, int len)
{
    int index = rand() % len;
    return tiles[index];
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    const char * tiles = "T~.";
    int len = strlen(tiles);

    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << generator(tiles, len) << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoops, forgot about the difference between `''` and `""` when copying the code over.

Answer (score 4):

Doing rand that way is bad.

The exact value of RAND_MAX can very but is usually 32767 (or multiples thereof).
This means `rand() % 3` gives you:

```
  0:     1/10923   // Notice that 0 and 1
  1:     1/10923   // have a slightly higher probability.
  2:     1/10922
```

There are all sorts of other issues with rand. So you may want to look at the new random libraries provided with C++11.

But if you want to use rand() in the most non biased way possible.

```
 int getRand(int max)
 {
     int max = RAND_MAX/max*max; // Note integer division
                                 // So /max*max does not cancel out.

     int val;
     do
     {
          val = rand();
     } while(val >= max);

     return val % max;
}
```

At least that will give you an even distribution.